# String Function to Get Left 1000, But Only To Last Period or Carriage Return

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have blocks of text, anywhere between 500 and 2000 characters long.

What I need to be able to do is take a maximum of 1000 characters from the description but only to the last full stop or carriage return (Char(13)), so that the text isn't cut off mid-sentence. Should there be both periods and Char(13)'s I would ideally like it to cut if off at the period.

I'm pasting some randomly generated text to try and show what I mean.

> *Up unpacked friendly ecstatic so possible humoured do. Ample ended might folly quiet one set spoke her. We no am former valley assure.
>   Four need spot ye said we find mile. Are commanded him convinced
>   dashwoods did estimable forfeited. Shy celebrated met sentiments she
>   reasonably but. Proposal its disposed eat advanced marriage sociable.
>   Drawings led greatest add subjects endeavor gay remember. Principles
>   one yet assistance you met impossible. The who arrival end how fertile
>   enabled. Brother she add yet see minuter natural smiling article
>   painted. Themselves at dispatched interested insensible am be
>   prosperous reasonably it. She boisterous use friendship she dissimilar considered expression. Sex quick arose mrs lived. Mr things do plenty others an vanity myself
>   waited to. Always parish tastes at as mr father dining at. Led ask
>   possible mistress relation elegance eat likewise debating.
>
> Or am nothing amongst chiefly address. The its enable direct men
>   depend highly. Ham windows sixteen who inquiry fortune demands. Is be
>   upon sang fond must shew. Really boy law county she unable her sister.
>   Feet you off its like like six. Among sex are leave law built now. In
>   built table in an rapid blush. Merits behind on afraid or warmly. In either so spring wished. Melancholy wayBy message*

I would want to be able to return all text up to "chiefly address." (990 characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the original requirement -- 1000 max characters, up to the last period, but there might not be any period -- the following would work:

```sql
LEFT(LEFT(string, 1000),
     1001 - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(LEFT(string, 1000))))
```

The `LEFT(string, 1000)` is used as the expression to take the `LEFT(expression, some number)` from because it ensures that no more than 1000 characters will be taken which would otherwise happen in the case of the string not having any periods at all. While the `LEFT(expression, 1000)` could have instead been wrapped around the entire `LEFT(string, 1001 - ...)`, doing it the way shown above should allow for the expression to be reused since it also shows up exactly the same inside of the `REVERSE` function, hence a little more efficient.

For the updated requirement of introducing a Carriage Return as a fall-back character to look for, you can maybe switch to using `PATINDEX` as it can look for a list of characters:

```sql
LEFT(LEFT(string, 1000),
     1001 - PATINDEX('%[.' + CHAR(13) + ']%', REVERSE(LEFT(string, 1000))))
```

However, there is one final requirement added:

> Should there be both periods and Char(13)'s I would ideally like it to cut if off at the period.

Unfortunately, `PATINDEX` can't distinguish which one comes first. At this point it seems like some form of conditional logic will need to be added :-(.

```sql
LEFT(LEFT(TestData, 1000), 1001 - IIF(CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(LEFT(TestData, 1000))) > 0,
                                      CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(LEFT(TestData, 1000))),
                                      CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), REVERSE(LEFT(TestData, 1000))))
                                     )
```

Here I not only reused the `LEFT(TestData, 1000)`, but the `REVERSE(LEFT(TestData, 1000))` shows up 3 times, and for the `IIF` (which is really just shorthand for `CASE WHEN x THEN y ELSE x END`) I reused the entire `CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(LEFT(TestData, 1000)))`.

---

The example code is posted on Pastebin.com at:

[Get 1000 chars max, up to final period, else to final return](http://pastebin.com/2Ee5Lmp5)

The example shows the outcome of the 3 methods shown above across 7 different test cases.

Answer (score 5):

Edit: This was posted to address an earlier version.

The left 1000 characters are easy.

Then find the first period in the reverse of the left 1000. That's how much you should subtract from the original 1000.

Like:

```
LEFT(@s, 
    1001-
    CHARINDEX('.', 
        REVERSE(LEFT(@s,1000))
    )
)
```

...I think - you may have to add one somewhere if it wipes the period or leaves a space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31662/discussion-between-srutzky-and-pix1985).

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this Pix, see if it works for you.
Just change the declared variable to a column in a table and remove the set statement. At least it will give you a template to go off of.

```
declare @notes varchar(2000);

set @notes = 'Up unpacked friendly ecstatic so possible humoured do. Ample ended might folly quiet one set spoke her. We no am former valley assure. Four need spot ye said we find mile. Are commanded him convinced dashwoods did estimable forfeited. Shy celebrated met sentiments she reasonably but. Proposal its disposed eat advanced marriage sociable. Drawings led greatest add subjects endeavor gay remember. Principles one yet assistance you met impossible. The who arrival end how fertile enabled. Brother she add yet see minuter natural smiling article painted. Themselves at dispatched interested insensible am be prosperous reasonably it. In either so spring wished. Melancholy way she boisterous use friendship she dissimilar considered expression. Sex quick arose mrs lived. Mr things do plenty others an vanity myself waited to. Always parish tastes at as mr father dining at. Led ask possible mistress relation elegance eat likewise debating. By message or am nothing amongst chiefly address. The its enable direct men depend highly. Ham windows sixteen who inquiry fortune demands. Is be upon sang fond must shew. Really boy law county she unable her sister. Feet you off its like like six. Among sex are leave law built now. In built table in an rapid blush. Merits behind on afraid or warmly.'

select start_off = @notes;

-- select length_1000 = substring(@notes, 0, 1000); -- the full 1000

-- select last_full_stop = charindex('.', reverse(left(@notes, 1000))); -- use 1000 - this number to get the last full stop

-- select right(left(@notes, 1000), 1); -- the character at the 1000 position

select  potential_answer = 
        case when right(left(@Test, 1000), 1) = '.' then Left(@Test,1000)
        else substring(@Test, 1, 1000 - charindex('.', reverse(left(@Test, 1000))) + 1) -- add 1 to add in the full stop
        end
```

Probably not the best, but it works with your example.